# subscribe to done event in datetime picker in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

How to subscribe to the done event i.e., I want to call a function after selecting the date. How can i do that in ionic2

```
 <ion-icon class="moreicon" name="funnel">
    <ion-datetime type="button" [(ngModel)]="myDate" (click)="getData()"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-icon>
```

In ts file i called this function but my problem is on first select of date my data is not filtered. Again when i click on filter icon then my filtered data is displayed. So I want to subscribe the done event in datetime picker. How can i do that??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `ionChange()` as shown below. [**Doc here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#output-events).

```
    <ion-icon class="moreicon" name="funnel">
     <ion-datetime type="button" [(ngModel)]="myDate" (ionChange)="getData()">
     </ion-datetime>
   </ion-icon>
```

**subscribe** : [**Doc**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/datetime/datetime.ts#L502)

```
picker.ionChange.subscribe(() => {
  this.validate(picker);
});
```

Comment: Is it me or it is not in the documentation ? At least the link you gave.

Comment: It is an issue of the Ionic doc.See this: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-site/issues/1074 @AngePicard

Comment: Ok, I was using this component but with a refresh button as I couldn't find an output event. I was wondering how Ionic devs could miss that out. Thank you !

Comment: Why can't you use `(ionChange)`? That is the `output event` here? @AngePicard

Comment: @Sampath Haha, I was just saying that I wasn't aware of the event before reading your answer. I'm using it now and it's way better.